# Ext.Net and Ext.JS

Tags: extjs, ext.net

Good Day Guys,

I know this may sound like a stupid question. However, I wonder if someone can please explain to me the difference between **EXT.NET** and **EXT.JS**..

I have been trying to understand both of them, but the result is zero. As far as I know, EXT.NET integrates EXT.JS..

I don't understand... When doing my research, sometimes it redirects me to **SenchaJS**.. But sometimes to http://examples.ext.net/

How do they both work actually ?

If it is possible, can you please provide me with some tutorial as well ?

Thanks a lot guys..

Comment: All markup written in Ext.Net will be sent to the browser as ExtJS javascript code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ExtJS is a JavaScript framework for building rich UI's for web applications. It leverages advanced CSS and JavaScript to bring a desktop like presentation to the browser.

Ext.net is a .Net specific implementation of ExtJS allowing very easing integration with WebForms.

In a nutshell if you're a .Net developer and you want to save a good deal of work you might checkout Ext.net otherwise ExtJS is the product you want to use. That said ExtJS can be used with .Net just fine without using Ext.net. Also keep in mind that with Ext.net is currently based off of an older version of the ExtJS library(3.4.0) whereas ExtJS is currently at version 4.

[ExtJS 4.0 Resources](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/)

Comment: What is not clear for you? :) You can ask this question in Ext.NET forum. http://forums.ext.net

Comment: Currently, Ext.NET v2 is based on ExtJS 4. Also it doesn't support ASP.NET MVC including the Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, Ext.NET is a bridge from ExtJS to the .NET environment. If you've already been using Javascript, then I would probably go the pure ExtJS route, as Ext.NET just generates ExtJS code for what you've expressed in the .NET environment using the Ext.NET controls.

I started in ExtJS, despite being from a .NET environment, but got pushed the Ext.NET route due to conforming the code base technology - I also saw that maybe there was some development speed advantages. I now find I'm structuring the page elements in Ext.NET, and programming events, etc in ExtJS (javascript).

Either way, even using Ext.NET you will end up writing some Javascript code. On the plus side, Javascript is not as hard as it looks after a few hours of experience, especially if you've ever programmed in 'C'.

Answer (score 1):

Ext.NET (v2) is well underway and will include integration of Sencha ExtJS 4.
Full support for ASP.NET MVC (all View Engines, including Razor) will be built directly into the Ext.NET Assembly.

A private “Developer Preview” of Ext.NET v2 will be available soon

Comment: You should add this as a comment as its not really an answer.